# How to decrypt password from terraform output

Tags: terraform, keybase

How can I decrypt generated passwords from output like this:

```
passwords = {
    "user-1" = "encrypted_password_by_keybase"
    "user-2" = "encrypted_password_by_keybase"
    "user-2" = "encrypted_password_by_keybase"
    .... etc
}
```

I was trying to use

```
terraform output -json passwords | jq '.value[0]' |  base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt
```

but obviously i'm doing it wrong. Help please.

Edit: after command `terraform output -json passwords` I'm getting:

```
{
   "user_name_1":"string like XI/VTnmEJxRlOA1h79qZRbgXY+L",
   "user_name_2":"string like XI/VTnmEJxRlOA1h79qZRbgXY+L"
   ....etc
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? And what does the JSON output look like when you run `terraform output -json passwords`? Do you get an error when you run the command in the question? If so can you edit your question to include it please?

Comment: Edited question with output